# Malfuncionamiento Google sites. Redirecciona a otro sitio

Tags: redirección, dominio, google-sites

El dominio es [www.sistemadau.com](http://www.sistemadau.com)
Contratado en doominio.com.
Seguimos sus instrucciones para conectar dominio a página creada en Google sites.
La página creada en Google sites ya esta publicada hará unos 10 días.
Problema:
Al poner en caja urls la dirección URL [www.sistemadau.com](http://www.sistemadau.com) sino has entrado en cualquiera de tus cuentas de Gmail te redirige a la página de ¡Gmail¡
Además al poco rato la caja URL pasa de tener el nombre [www.sistemadau.com](http://www.sistemadau.com) a la dirección de la página de Google sites

Agradecemos mucho ayuda
:)
Gracias!

Comment: No veo el problema, y no estoy logeado en Google. Ya que es un negocio, no te conviene pagar tu propio hosting mejor??